# Processing Django form gives x (many to many) field is an invalid keyword argument

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm building a site with UserProfiles, contacts, and Events. I created a form to add new events linked to a UserProfile, with members selected from the UserProf's list of contacts.
At first an Event had a ForeignKey to a contact, the EventForm was ModelChoice, and everything worked. I could process the form and the contact was added to the Event, and the Event added to the logged-in UserProfile.

Then when I try to make an Event with ManyToManyField, and the EventForm ModelMultipleChoice, I get the 'members' is an invalid keyword argument for this function' error. Can't quite figure this one out. Really appreciate your help :)

views:

```
def add_events(request):
        user = request.user
        contacts_list = user.get_profile().contacts.all().order_by('first_name')
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = EventForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    na = form.cleaned_data['name']
                    da = form.cleaned_data['date']
                    de = form.cleaned_data['description']
                    me = form.cleaned_data['members']
                    event = Event.objects.create(user=user.get_profile(), name=na, date=da, description=de, members=me)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/events')
                else:
                    form.fields['members'].queryset = user.get_profile().contacts.all().order_by('first_name')
            else:
                form = EventForm()
                form.fields['members'].queryset = user.get_profile().contacts.all().order_by('first_name')
            return render_to_response('add_events.html', {'user': user, 'form': form, 'usp': user.get_profile(), 'contacts_list': contacts_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models:

```
class EventForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    date = forms.DateField()
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    members = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Profile.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='event')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error could be raised by the line

```
event = Event.objects.create(user=user.get_profile(), name=na, date=da, description=de, members=me)
```

The `__init__()`  of `Model`, here the `Event`, only accepts assignments to normal fields and properties as `kwargs`, M2M fields are not accepted hence the error.

Change the code to below could solve the issue, check [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for the assignment of M2M.

```
event = Event.objects.create(user=user.get_profile(), name=na, date=da, description=de)
event.members = form.cleaned_data['members']
```

Comment: IIRC the last line should be `event.members.add(*form.cleaned_data['members'])`

Comment: okm, that works, thanks!
bruno, I'll give that a try too to see.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Both of them could work. The assignment is actually `.clear()` then `.add()`.